# Import and use a Maven managed Java library (CitySDK)

Tags: java, maven, import, dependency-management

I am trying to build a web application based on the project library [CitySDK](https://github.com/CitySDK/tourism_library_java), but i don't know how to import it properly into my own project.

I have created a Maven Web Application and added the CitySDK library as a Dependency, and then Selected the Project, right-clicked and Selected Build with Dependencies. No errors appeared, and in the image below you can see it appeared as a dependency.

However, whenever i try to use some of the classes specific to it, in my own Web Application(called TourismApplication's TestClass.java), the compiler displays an error, that the package is unknown. Could anyone suggest ideas as to what i have missed? I have followed a few Maven tutorials, but without any effects.

[image]

The dependencies are as follows:

[image]

Comment: I think you missed a couple of steps in your workflow... you got everything working using Maven, but you're doing something else that results in compiler errors? What exactly are you doing with these files?

Comment: i do not have any compiler errors; i want to use the imported library in my project, but it doesn't identify its objects. The compiler errors appear when i try to use the objects in the imported library.

Comment: Silly question, did you add the appropriate `import` statements?

Comment: i get an error with the import statements; as soon as i write import citysdk.*; i get an error; also, i should usually get an autocomplete for it, which i don't

Comment: What do you see when you expand the dependency for the CitySDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I did some digging and I think I figured out your problem. Their POM file is incorrect based on the structure of project.

First off, I'll paraphrase what I think the steps you took to get it built in your project were, to ensure I followed the same steps to get it working. These are the steps I took:

1. Cloned/downloaded the sources from the link you placed in the OP
2. Built the project into a jar file by running the command they said to use: `mvn clean package assembly:single`
3. Installed the artifact in your local Maven repo using `mvn install`
4. Added a dependency in your project POM

I tried the same thing you did, using the library in a test source file, to no avail. I looked at the .jar file that was built using their instructions and didn't find any .class files archived into it... it was essentially empty.

Turns out, their `src` folder structure follows Maven standards, but their POM file indicates the sources are down a different chain of directories. If you examine the build log closely, you see "[INFO] No sources to compile"

The POM.xml file they provide specifies the source directory as

```
<sourceDirectory>src/citysdk/tourism/client</sourceDirectory>
```

However, the actual files are at

```
src\main\java\citysdk\tourism\client
```

After changing the line in the POM file from the above to (similarly for tests):

```
<sourceDirectory>src/main/java/citysdk/tourism/client</sourceDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>src/test/java/citysdk/tourism/client/tests</testSourceDirectory>
```

rebuilt, and installed, it worked when I tried to use it in my project. Hope this helps.

FYI, I used IntelliJ as my IDE, but it should work the same with Eclipse.

Comment: You are awesome!!! I replaced the line in Netbeans, cleaned and built, and it worked!!! Thank you very very very much!